# Separate schema for Production/Dev/Test data in cloud database for mobile app development

Tags: android, ios, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-aurora

We have Android and iOS apps sending data to database in cloud(AWS). Apps are completely functional, but our customers are not liking the fact that we are storing the customers data and data generated while testing (QA,Dev,Staging) into same tables in the cloud.

Our apps sends data to REST Endpoints (viz., API Gateway in AWS), which passes this data to Java code and this java code writes the data to the DB in cloud.

We want to store the data generated by end users, developers, testers, alpha users into separate tables/schema in the cloud, so that data will be segregated accordingly (ex: developer may clean all tables every week, while QA may clean all tables after every release; while production data is archived every month etc).

In traditional desktop applications, we can have different schema of the same tables for dev, qa, prod environments and applications will write to appropriate schema based on some local configuration parameter.

How can I achieve the same effect for any Android and iOS apps where I will store dev, qa and prod data into different schema (QA I mean when iOS app is in testflight or android app is in alpha/beta channels; dev I mean when developers are doing dev testing; prod I mean the when end users have downloaded the app from app store or play store)

I reviewed CI discussion 
[Ideal dev/test/QA environment for development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915455/ideal-dev-test-qa-environment-for-development), but my question is not about development environments; it is about data segregation.

Any discussion or opinions are appreciated.

Comment: Note that while your question seems to have some merit, Stack Overflow is not intended for "discussion and opinion," see https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask.  It sounds as if you only have one set of REST endpoints, and that seems like the first problem with your setup, if true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We run something similar where I work and the best way, in my opinion, is to complete segregate the data. If you start mixing the data together by database flags or roles or whatever, you're going to have a bad time messing with production data.

To overcome this I highly recommend complete separate environments. We have completely separate AWS accounts for each environment (develop, staging and production).

For our mobile apps, we make a build for each environment we're testing. So for develop, we would have a develop config file that would have all the API URLs, account numbers, etc to control where the requests and data get sent to.

Depending on how you're using TestFlight and Google Play Beta/Alpha, you could do the same thing. Just do a new build for each environment. The issue you will run into is if your workflow is to promote those builds to production. They would need to be built with production configs.